# Convert RGB color to the nearest color in palette (web safe color)?

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a color either in RGB/Hex format to its nearest web-safe color.

Details about a websafe color can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_safe_color

This website(http://www.colortools.net/color_make_web-safe.html) is able to do the way I want to, but I am not sure how to go about it in Python. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You know 'web safe' colors aren't really important anymore, right? And weren't all they were cracked up to be in the first place. I bet that Wikipedia link you put here explains that, too.

Comment: I think the general task is interesting (who cares if the colors are from the "web safe" palette?) - step #1 is to find out: "How to compute the difference (and by what metric?) between two RGB values?" *Once such a difference function is defined, this task is easily solved trivially with a map and sort* (which is very boring).

Comment: Start by [color difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) to see just how complicated coming up with such a difference function can be! (And this is also very device and color-space dependent.)  Anyway, with these new search terms, should be able to explore more. Good luck!

Comment: e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754506/color-similarity-distance-in-rgba-color-space

Comment: Unlike other palettes, web safe colors don't need any complex comparison algorithms, because each channel is simply a multiple of 51. So you can take the channels of your own color and just do `R = Round( ( R / 255 ) * 5 ) * 51`. Fast and simple cross-platform color quantization. So much for being "not really important anymore"! ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Despite being somewhat of a misnomer, the web safe color palette is indeed quite useful for color quantization. It's simple, fast, flexible, and ubiquitous. It also allows for RGB hex shorthand such as `#369` instead of `#336699`. Here's a walkthrough:

1. Web safe colors are RGB triplets, with each value being one of the following six: `00, 33, 66, 99, CC, FF`. So we can divide the max RGB value `255` by five (one less than the total possible values) to get a multiple value, `51`.
2. Normalize the channel value by dividing by `255` (this makes it a value from `0-1` instead of `0-255`).
3. Multiply by `5`, and round the result to make sure it stays exact.
4. Multiply by `51` to get the final web safe value. All together, this looks something like:

   ```
   def getNearestWebSafeColor(r, g, b):
       r = int(round( ( r / 255.0 ) * 5 ) * 51)
       g = int(round( ( g / 255.0 ) * 5 ) * 51)
       b = int(round( ( b / 255.0 ) * 5 ) * 51)
       return (r, g, b)

   print getNearestWebSafeColor(65, 135, 211)
   ```

No need to go crazy comparing colors or creating huge lookup tables, as others have suggested. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this extremely useful and well working method! I've translated your generic code description into a Python function. However, the markup doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @SimonSteinberger: the problem with the markdown is that to insert a code block in an ordered list, we need to put 8 spaces instead of 4. :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
import scipy.spatial as sp

input_color = (100, 50, 25)
websafe_colors = [(200, 100, 50), ...] # list of web-save colors
tree = sp.KDTree(websafe_colors) # creating k-d tree from web-save colors
ditsance, result = tree.query(input_color) # get Euclidean distance and index of web-save color in tree/list
nearest_color = websafe_colors[result]
```

Or add loop for several `input_color`s

About [k-dimensional tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

Comment: Great solution for arbitrary palettes.